# check all domains in a crawler

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

```
class WebsiteSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "webcrawler"
    
    allowed_domains = ["www.reichelt.com", "cdn-reichelt.de"]
    start_urls = [""https://www.reichelt.com/""]
```

I am setting up crawler for the base start url. My crawler did not manage to crawl all sub links from my base url because some of them were on a different url. For example `cdn-reichelt.de`. Is there any way I can modify this such that my crawler crawls ALL domains that it encounters on that start url?

Comment: Add both urls in `start_urls`

Comment: Is there no other way? Because I want to run the script for several links in a list and wont know all possible domains manually @abdusco

Comment: you can just remove `allowed_domain`. If you _do_ want to keep it limited, you can add a property with the same name and build the domain list from `start_urls`: `@property def allowed_domains(self): return [url_to_domain(url) for url in self.start_urls]`